# What do we get from the diagonalization of the $k\cdot p$ matrix?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, approximations

In [k.p theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C2%B7p_perturbation_theory), we expand the wave function around a known point ${\bf k}_0$

$$u_{\lambda}({\bf k})=\sum_{\nu} c_{\lambda,\nu}({\bf k})u_{\nu}({\bf k}_0).$$

If we now consider 8 bands (conduction, heavy-hole, light-hole, split-off, each twice spin degenerate), over what states do we have to sum up? Would it the 8 bands or is the spin not included here and it is only 4 bands?

If we now solve the 8x8 k.p Hamiltonian for one point in momentum space, we get 8 eigenvalues and 8 eigenvectors of length 8. I want to make sure that I understand the connection to physics correctly: The 8 eigenvalues are the band energies of the 8 bands for that particular momentum. The 8 eigenvectors each have 8 entries which are the coefficients $c_{\lambda,\nu}$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else is asking himself the same question: The sum has to performed over all 8 bands, so including the spin. And for the second question, yes, the coefficients is what you get as the eigenvector.